# Question reg. HandleError attribute in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, handleerror

If I register the HandleError attribute in global.asax.cs file as below,

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

still I need to specify the HandlError attribute in all the controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't.  That's the whole point of global filters.

> Global filters run for every action of every controller.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg402080%28v=VS.98%29.aspx)